# The method addElem(MyClass) in the type Route is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, MyClass)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

```
Route tabulist = new Route();    
Map<Integer,MyClass> next = findClosest(tempRoute,tabulist);
    tabulist.addElem(next.get("index"),next.get("myclass"));

private Map<Integer,MyClass> findClosest(...)
{
  // ...
  return next.put(22,myClassElem);
}
```

The compiler says "The method addElem(MyClass) in the type Route is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, MyClass)". However inside the class Route I have the method:

```
public void addElem(Integer i, MyClass elem) {
    Elems.add(i,elem);
}
```

How to retrieve the data `22` and `myClassElem`?

Comment: Show your full class.

Comment: `next.get()` is expecting an `Integer`, not a `String`.

Comment: `put` returns the value, not the map. Do you have a map of maps? If `next` is a map of `<Integer>, <MyClass>`, what does `next.get("index")` mean? `"index"` is not an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  `**Sotirios Delimanolis**` said  get is expecting an integer and you should pass integer to get method instead of string

like

```
next.get(11)
```

to add element try the below code

```
tabulist.addElem( 11 , new MyClass());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  tabulist.addElem(next.get("index"),next.get("myclass"));
```

This line should be replaced with

```
  tabulist.addElem(<whatever integer>, next.get("myclass"));
```